# Audio not playing on chrome-android (Kitkat 4.4.2 on LG G Pro 2 D838) via HTTPS

Tags: android, google-chrome, audio, ssl, https

I am having issues playing an audio file on the chrome browser on mobile LG G Pro-2(D838) running Kitkat 4.4.2.

This [audio file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9f/Sample_of_%22Another_Day_in_Paradise%22.ogg) plays on the chrome browser on my mobile without any issues. But when i uploaded the same file to our server and tried to open it on chrome browser, it does not play. Here is the [link](https://frontend.lifetape.com/download/p_ml/test/Sample_of_Another_Day_in_Paradise.ogg) to the file at our server.

Now the server is configured for HTTPS access only. When I tried playing the file after enabling HTTP access, the audio played. Also, the images and other content on our server is accessible on the same mobile device via HTTPS. The audio file also plays on other mobile devices running same Android version(Google Nexus 4 running 4.4.2).

We are using certificate provided by StartSSL(free version).

Is there something wrong with the SSL certificate we are using? Or is it the problem with the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the problem with Server Name Identification(SNI). Check this [Link](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/84545/71045)